# How to test the output from Kafka?

Tags: file-upload, apache-kafka, flume-ng

I am trying to integrate Flume and Kafka where Flume takes a data file and pushes to Kafka and then to Spark.

I saw this config file from a blog and named as flafka.conf:

```
 tier1.sources  = source1
 tier1.channels = channel1
 tier1.sinks    = sink1

 tier1.sources.source1.type = exec
 tier1.sources.source1.command = /Users/name1/test.txt
 tier1.sources.source1.channels = channel1

 tier1.channels.channel1.type   = memory
 tier1.channels.channel1.capacity = 10000
 tier1.channels.channel1.transactionCapacity = 1000

 tier1.sinks.sink1.type         = org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink
 tier1.sinks.sink1.topic = sink1
 tier1.sinks.sink1.brokerList = kafkagames-1:9092,kafkagames-2:9092
 tier1.sinks.sink1.channel = channel1
 tier1.sinks.sink1.batchSize = 20
```

Then I ran this command:

```
bin/flume-ng agent --conf conf --conf-file flafka.conf --name a1 -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console
```

How do I test if I can see the contents of test.txt file in Kafka. Please advice. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try kafka console consumer in order to check if something is written to kafka topic. So you push the file from flume and wait in console consumer to see it in kafka topic.

Kafka console consumer description can be find here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/System+Tools